# Webclient call to Core API can't find endpoint if using FromBody and FromForm parameter is always null/new

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webclient

Here's the API code snippit:

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(myObject), 201)] //created
[ProducesResponseType(500)] //server error
public IActionResult Create([FromForm]myObject myObj) {
...
```

Here's the server-side call:

```
...
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {        
    NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
    string targetURL = "https://localhost:44317/api/MyController/Create"
    string callMethod = "POST";
    formData["myObj"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj);
    var thingy = client.UploadValues(targetURL, callMethod, formData);
    ...
```

If I use `[FromForm]`, the call finds the endpoint but the data passed in is as if I had said `myObj = new MyObject();` with default values for everything. So... not *exactly* null.

If I use `[FromBody]`, `client` cant' find the url and I get a `400 Bad Request`.

I've read the numerous posts here and elsewhere and they don't exactly cover this situation, I think, since what I'm observing seems to be backwards from what everyone else is asking. So I'm not exactly sure what's going on with my code.

Note that I cannot use *async* so I can't use HttpClient. (Can't use async because this is inside of a Kentico site and this is an ascx inside a portal page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are intending to post JSON, but you're actually posting as `x-www-form-urlencoded` with the serialized JSON as a value for a `myObj` param. Because of the encoding type, the action must use `[FromForm]` (or no attribute at all), but at that point, it cannot deserialize your "JSON" into an object. I use "JSON" in quotes here because in actuality, it's just a string. ASP.NET Core has no idea whatsoever that this is even JSON, nor that it should do something with it. Long and short, you need to post with an actual `application/json` request body.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    var requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj));
    var response = webClient.UploadData(targetUrl, callMethod, requestBody);
}
```

Then, of course, you'll need to actually use the `FromBody` attribute on your param, since now you will in fact be receiving JSON.

Comment: Question: how would I do this if I had two params in the API metehod signature. Say a string and a myObj?

Comment: You cannot have multiple action params from the request body. You *may* have params other than what's marked as `[FromBody]`, but only if they are obtained from the URL. For example, you could do `MyAction(int id, [FromBody]Foo foo)` with a route like `/foo/{id}`. Otherwise, all posted information must go in the class you're binding to. If you need additional data that can't be held in your `MyObject` class, then you'd need to create a wrapper class with property(ies) for that additional data and one for your `MyObject` reference.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with `FromForm` is that you serialize it to string and WebAPI won't deserialize it for your by default. If you want to continue with `FromForm` you can change parameter type to string and deserialize it explicitly:

```
public IActionResult Create([FromForm]string myObj) {
    myObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myObject>(myObj);
    ...
```

Comment: Nope, `string myObj` is null when it comes across. Just tried it.